# Jtable not returning the last cell value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

This is my Table class

```
package build;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Table
{
private ArrayList<Column> columns;
private String NAME;
private static int count=0;
public Table() 
{
    setColumns(new ArrayList<Column>());
    NAME=new String();

    this.NAME="Table"+count;
    count++;
}

public void AddColumn(Column column)
{
    for(Column c: getColumns())
    {
       if(c.getname().equals(column.getname())){return;}
    }

    getColumns().add(column);

}
public int getCount(){return count;}
public void SaveToFile() throws IOException
{


    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Ashad/Desktop/text.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
     bw.write("\r\n");
    bw.write(this.NAME);
     bw.write("\r\n");

 for(Column c: getColumns())
 {
 bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.write(c.getname()+"  ");

        bw.write(c.getdatatype()+"  ");


 if(c.getPK()== true)
 {
        bw.write("true"+"  ");

 }    
    else
    {   bw.write("false"+"  ");

    }
if(c.getNN()== true)
{
    bw.write("true"+"   ");

}     
else
    {bw.write("false"+"  "); } 



 }
 bw.close();
}

  public boolean DeleteColumn(String name)
  {
    for (Column c : getColumns())
    {
        if (c.getname().equals(name)) {return getColumns().remove(c);}
    }
    return false;
  }

 public void viewColumns()
 {
      System.out.append(NAME+"  ");

    for(Column c: getColumns())
    {
      System.out.append("\n");
      System.out.append(c.getname()+"  ");

      System.out.append( c.getdatatype()+"  ");

      if(c.getPK()== true)
      {
         System.out.print(true);
      }   
          else
        System.out.print(false);  
      }
     }

public String getNAME() {

    return NAME;
}

public ArrayList<Column> getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setColumns(ArrayList<Column> columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}



  }
```

JTable

```
 table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(

                  new Object[][] {
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},

                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  {null, null, null, null},
                  },
        new String[] {
            "Column Name", "Data Type", "NN", "PK"
                        }
              ) {
                    Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                String.class, Object.class, Boolean.class, Boolean.class
            };
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
        }
```

The Button below saves the values that were inserted on the Jtable to the objects of the table.

```
 btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
   {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      // getTable Values 
       for (int r = 0; r < model.getRowCount(); r++)
        {
           if((String)model.getValueAt(r, 0) != null)
         {

                    Column col=new Column();

            col.setname((String) model.getValueAt(r, 0)) ;
            col.setdatatype((String) model.getValueAt(r, 1));


             /*  if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(r, 2)== true)
                       {
                col.setPK(true); 
               }


             if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(r, 3)== true)
               {
                    col.setNN(true); 
                    }
               */

                    T.AddColumn(col);

             }
                else 
                       break;
            }
           try {
            T.SaveToFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
            T.viewColumns();
           frame.setVisible(false); 
                        }
                    });
```

PROBLEM :: 
* Its not saving the last value for example if the last inserted value is at model.getValueAt(1, 1) or its at model.getValueAt(2, 1)

if input on Jtable is        Type1   int
                             Type2   char

Output which above code gives :: Type1   int
                                 Type2

- Second problem is on uncommenting

  if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(r, 2)== true)
                     {
              col.setPK(true); 
             }
                    and

  if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(r, 3)== true)
                     {
              col.setPK(true); 
             }

It gives error as return type is boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Its not saving the last value

Maybe [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) will help.

Comment: no that is not my problem; i have a saving mechanism ; problem lies in the for loop where model.getValueAt(r, 2) is taking place. I couldnot figure out the problem that why its not saving the last value