# JTable last value null

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm creating a little game. So now I have a JTable with only 5 rows.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) usernameTable.getModel();
dtm.setColumnCount(1);
dtm.setRowCount(5);
```

After I click a button, I want to save the values from the table. My problem is that the last value is every time **null**.

**Example**

> Val from Table : user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
>   Expected output: [user1, user2, user3, user4, user5]
>   Output: [user1, user2, user3, user4, null]

*This is how I'm getting the data from the table*

```
ArrayList<String> username = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < usernameTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
    username.add(usernamTable.getValueAt(i, 0);
}
```

**Runnable Example**

```
public class JtableNullExample {
    private JTable usernameTable;
    private JPanel usernamePane;
    private JButton sendButton;
    private ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JtableNullExample();
    }

    public JtableNullExample() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Setting Table Model
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) usernameTable.getModel();
        dtm.setColumnCount(1);
        dtm.setRowCount(5);

        frame.setContentPane(usernamePane);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        sendButton.addActionListener(e -> {

            for (int count = 0; count < usernameTable.getRowCount(); count++) {

                System.out.println(usernameTable.getValueAt(count, 0));
                userList.add(usernameTable.getValueAt(count, 0).toString());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted give us no hint about about problem. Please create a small runnable class ([mcve]) that demonstrate your problem. In this case we can also debug it to provide a solution that is suitable for your code.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I updated my Question. But I think I have found a solution to it. (Look at my solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution.
The problem is, that JTable doesn't know if we're finished with editing the cell.

```
if (usernameTable.isEditing()) {
   usernameTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
}
```

This will stop editing the cell and now you shouldn't get any null value anymore.

Solution:
https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/

[Jtable not returning the last cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267980/jtable-not-returning-the-last-cell-value)